# How to create programmatically single LINQ query w/ OR between Where() clauses (.Where(fn) OR .Where(fn) OR .Where(fn)) programatically

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'd like to know it is it possible to create programmatically single LINQ query (for EntityFramework 6) with N `.Where()` clauses, but with OR between these `.Where()` clauses.

Imagine IQueryable object defined like:

```
var query = dbContext.MyTable.Where(mt => mt.TimeStamp >= DateBegin);
```

What I need else is add N (unknown number) of Where clauses, but with OR condition between them.

Image list of some object:

```
List<MyObject> myObj = 
  new List<MyObject>({new MyObject {val = "a" }, new MyObject { val = "b"}}); //In real code there is more than 1 property.
```

then I'd like to add Where() clauses to query like:

```
myObj.ForEach(mo =>{
   // THIS CREATES -AND- BETWEEN WHERE CLAUSES, BUT I NEED -OR-
   query.Where(q=>q.MyValue == mo.val); // In real code there is more than 1 property to compare
});
```

I was thinking about `.Union()` beteween queries, but It could generate union between separated queries and it's not optimal I think.

Thanks!

Comment: not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but could you use contains? if you are checking to see if MyValue is one of the values in your list?

Comment: Do you need to filter just by one property e.g. `q.MyValue` or by multiple e.g. `Where(q => q.MyValue1 == value1 || q.MyValue2 == value2)` ?

Comment: @FRoZeN: unfortunatelly Contains() is not suitable here because I need to compare few properties and MyTable object and MyObject object aren't same

Comment: @takemyoxygen is also not suitable because I don't know number of objects in my List<T> obejct. This is the point of question.

Comment: In this case you need to build each property comparison to a separate `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` instance and then combine them. Take a look at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx Just let me know if you need more code samples for your scenario

Comment: @takemyoxygen I tried to avoid Union()... this could be a possible solution, but let me try. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a `Union()`, it's just creating the same expression (and therefore the same SQL) as you do with `Where(q => q.MyVal1 == val1 || q.MyVal2 == val2 ||..)` but with some more code. And this will result in a single SQL query with bunch of clauses separated by `OR`.

Comment: You can use PredicateBuilder : http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: @takemyoxygen You were right! This is working solution: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution: [linq-to-entities-combining-predicates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx)

Or course is necessary to use "latest" answer:

Copy/Paste `class ParameterRebinder`

Copy/Paste `static class Utility`

Usage:

```
Expression<Func<Car, bool>> theCarIsRed = c => c.Color == "Red";
Expression<Func<Car, bool>> theCarIsCheap = c => c.Price < 10.0;
Expression<Func<Car, bool>> theCarIsRedOrCheap = theCarIsRed.Or(theCarIsCheap);
var query = carQuery.Where(theCarIsRedOrCheap);
```

Because in my solution is N of expressions, I take first expression and then append other expressions in ForEach cycle.

```
var firstExpression = expressionList.First();
expressionList.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(ex => { firstExpression = firstExpression.Or(ex); });
```